# How To Access localhost server from the Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to access API endpoint on localhost from Android Emulator running on ubuntu 16.04.

I have configured my API endpoint inside my application to point to `10.0.2.2`

Android documentation specify that in order to communicate with localhost on host machine one has to use 10.0.2.2 IP Address [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html)

```
string endPoint = 'http://10.0.2.2/api';
```

My host machine server is running on port 80 using Laravel 5.3 server

```
sudo php artisan serve --port=80
```

Also, note that I have made the endpoint inside my Android application to point to my local machine IP address

```
192.168.8.112
```

However, still not able to communicate with the API

My device emulator details are as follows:

```
Name: Nexus_5X_API_27

CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86)

Path: /home/iarnous/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_27.avd

Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 27)

Skin: nexus_5x

SD Card: 100 MiB

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 1920

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: Nexus 5X

vm.heapSize: 256

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.lcd.width: 1080

hw.gps: yes

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 27

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86/

tag.id: google_apis_playstore

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: emulated

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: Nexus_5X_API_27

hw.camera.front: emulated

hw.lcd.density: 420

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5X API 27

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.device.hash2: MD5:bc5032b2a871da511332401af3ac6bb0

hw.ramSize: 1536

hw.trackBall: no

PlayStore.enabled: true

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.cpu.ncore: 2

hw.sdCard: no

tag.display: Google Play

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Much appreciated for your help.

Thanks

Comment: first try to access your API from the emulator's web browser for example.

Comment: @vladMatvienko You have made my day. Thank you. Internet connection on the emulator was turned off. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @valdMatvienko to draw my attention that I was not able having internet access on my Emulator.

The steps I put forth works fine, what I was missing was having my internet enabled on my virtual emulator.

Thanks